# Starting Weka from command line through C#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, weka

I am trying to open Weka from cmd line, using C#. This is the code that I'm using. It's giving me an error for Weka.Start() line, and the error is : Win32 exception was unhandled. System cannot find the file specified. Please help me out. Thanks

```
 ProcessStartInfo WekaStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Weka-    3-6\java -Xmx1536m -jar weka.jar");


        WekaStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        WekaStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        WekaStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        WekaStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process Weka = new Process();
        Weka.StartInfo = WekaStartInfo;
        Weka.Start();
        string output = Weka.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Weka.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to start WEKA from a
C# application.

1. In the WEKA install directory there is a
   batch file called RunWeka.bat. To start WEKA
   using this batch file use the following
   code:

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo wekaStartInfo = 
            new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\runweka.bat", "default");

   wekaStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Program Files\Weka-3-6";

   wekaStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   wekaStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   wekaStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   wekaStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

   using(Process weka = new Process())
   {
     weka.StartInfo = wekaStartInfo;
     weka.Start();
   }
   ```
2. To start WEKA without using the batch file
   use the following code:

   ```
   ProcessStartInfo wekaStartInfo = 
       new ProcessStartInfo(@"javaw", @"-classpath . RunWeka -i .\RunWeka.ini -w .\weka.jar -c default");

   wekaStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\Program Files\Weka-3-6";
   wekaStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   wekaStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   wekaStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
   wekaStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

   using(Process weka = new Process())
   {
     weka.StartInfo = wekaStartInfo;
     weka.Start();           
   }
   ```

In both cases you have to set the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably specified incorrect or inexistent location for your process based on the error description. Check that the path specified in ProcessStartInfo is correct.

Maybe, there are unnecessary spaces in the declaration here:

```
ProcessStartInfo WekaStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\java -Xmx1536m -jar weka.jar");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of ProcessStartInfo you must either enter just the [application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27xafxda.aspx) name, or specify the arguments [separate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe.aspx);

```
ProcessStartInfo WekaStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
                                  @"C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\java.exe",
                                  @"-Xmx1536m -jar weka.jar");
```